# Automatically generate IDs on SWT-Widgets

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, gui-testing, ui-testing

Is there a way to automatically generate IDs on SWT-Widgets so UI-Tests can reference them? I know i can manually set an id using seData but I want to implement this feature for an existing application in a somewhat generic fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can recursively assign IDs for all your shells in your application using `Display.getCurrent().getShells();` and `Widget.setData();`.

**Setting the IDs**

```
Shell []shells = Display.getCurrent().getShells();

for(Shell obj : shells) {
    setIds(obj);
}
```

You have access to all the active (not disposed) Shells in your application with the method `Display.getCurrent().getShells();` . You can loop through all children of each `Shell` and assign an ID to each `Control` with the method `Widget.setData();`.

```
private Integer count = 0;

private void setIds(Composite c) {
    Control[] children = c.getChildren();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < children.length; j++) {
        if(children[j] instanceof Composite) {
            setIds((Composite) children[j]);
        } else {
            children[j].setData(count);
            System.out.println(children[j].toString());
            System.out.println(" '-> ID: " + children[j].getData());
            ++count;
        }
    }
}
```

If the `Control` is a `Composite` it may have controls inside the composite, that's the reason I have used a recursive solution in my example.

---

**Finding Controls by ID**

Now, if you like to find a Control in one of your shells I would suggest a similar, recursive, approach:

```
public Control findControlById(Integer id) {
    Shell[] shells = Display.getCurrent().getShells();

    for(Shell e : shells) {
        Control foundControl = findControl(e, id);
        if(foundControl != null) {
            return foundControl;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private Control findControl(Composite c, Integer id) {
    Control[] children = c.getChildren();
    for(Control e : children) {
        if(e instanceof Composite) {
            Control found = findControl((Composite) e, id);
            if(found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        } else {
            int value = id.intValue();
            int objValue = ((Integer)e.getData()).intValue();

            if(value == objValue)
                return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

With the method `findControlById()` you can easily find a `Control` by it's ID.

```
    Control foundControl = findControlById(12);
    System.out.println(foundControl.toString());
```

**Links**

- [SWT API: Widget](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html)
- [SWT API: Display](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html)