# Identifying controls uniquely in an SWT application

Tags: java, swt

How to identify controls in an SWT application uniquely? Some Controls may be inactive at first but later activated. Is there a way to identify and assign unique ids to all the controls?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721105/automatically-generate-ids-on-swt-widgets

Answer (score 2):

You can associate arbitrary data with a control using the `setData` and `getData` methods:

```
control.setData("id key", "control id");

String id = (String)control.getData("id key");
```

Comment: This method of setting and retrieving data works fine and runs perfectly when invoked at the beginning of the application, is there a generic way to identify uniquely, the controls created at runtime(like a popup shell)?

Comment: There is no generic way, you have to code it yourself. Normally it is not necessary to do this.

Comment: okay, I've coded it till the setting of IDs at the beginning of the application, but is there a way to get alerts on the generation of a new shell? Like a notification when some part of the code creates a new shell ?

Comment: You can use `Display.addFilter` to listen for `SWT.Activate` events to see new shells, but the controls in the shell probably haven't been created at that point.

Comment: Alright ! I'm trying to check if a widget has an ID or is null, if it's null then i'm calling setData on it again, you're right, the controls in the shell won't be activated if i call display.addFilter on SWT.Activate

Answer (score 1):

Every SWT widget (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget`) has:

> getData
>
> public Object getData(String key)
>
> Returns the application defined property of the receiver with the specified name, 
>   or null if it has not been set.
>   Applications may have associated arbitrary objects with the receiver in this 
>   fashion. If the objects stored in the properties need to be notified when the 
>   widget is disposed of, it is the application's responsibility to hook the Dispose 
>   event on the widget and do so.

You can use this is conjunction with `public void setData(String key, Object value)`

Comment: This way i can only get and set the ids at the beginning of the application, what if i need to set the ID of the controls that are generated at runtime like a popup shell ?

Comment: Just call setData again, with the same key

Comment: the keys are inactive at the start of the application and may get activated at runtime based on inputs. How can I programmatically know if a new Control has been created so that i can set the ID at runtime Or call setData()?

Comment: Just read the doc I posted: getData() Returns the application defined property of the receiver with the specified name, __or null if it has not been set__. If you get null you haven't set this property

Comment: okay! so if i get null then probably i'll have to set the data with the key,value pair !! Alright , got it .. thanks a lot :)